# MapReduce Context.nextKeyValue() bug for the last splitted block

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mapreduce

I'm using MapReduce to train some models during the mapper phase. To do so, I need to spot the last line of input in my mapper phase. To do so, I use the following function: `Context.nextKeyValue()` that returns a boolean: `True` if there is a value after and `False` otherwise.

In my example my data are split into 6 differents blocks in HDFS. 5 of them have the same size and the last one is a bit smaller. We know that each mapper work on one block only.

When I try the function `Context.nextKeyValue()`, it works well for the 5 first mapper (those that have the same block size) but not for the last one for which the function always returns `True`!

I read about the mechanism:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    setup(context);
    while(context.nextKeyValue()){
        map(context.setCurrentKey(),context.getCurrentValue(),context)
    }
    cleanup(context);
}
```

My question is, did I do something wrong? Someone has an idea of what's happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on the version of MapReduce you're using, you can implement the `close()` (old) or `cleanup()` (new) method in your mapper class. It runs after all input has been processed by the current mapper. It's usually used to close connections to databases etc.

Comment: Can you remove all the random bold?

Comment: @BenWatson : Thanks for your answer. 
I load the data with the mapper and then construct my ARFF file to then train one model per mapper.
But once they are trained, I will predict a validation data-set and those predictions will serve as new features for the reducer task (only one reducer in this case) to train an other model that will aggregate the answers and so forth, create the ensemble ! 
Do you think that it's possible to pass the predictions from the ´cleanup ()´ to the red ?

Comment: @SterlingArcher, first of all i love this tv show and sorry it's my first post on stack overflow.

Comment: @YassineBoujida assuming we're not talking about a lot of data here, you should have your mapper's `cleanup()` save your predictions to a file on the HDFS, then have the reducer read that data in its `setup()` so it's available to all reducers.

Comment: @BenWatson By using the following class `FSDataOutputStream`, am I right ? Does it mean it's not possible to save the predictions in the mapper's `map()` function ?

Also, to solve this problem, I get the line and I check if the line isn't empty using `String.isEmpty()` rather than `nextKeyValue()`